# Loading background image relative to website location

Tags: html, css, background-image

I am currently building my own webpage and right now, it looks like that.

[image]

The goal is to have the wide header background image load relative to the document path:

The container for the Image looks like this:

```html
<header style="background-image: url('../../images/header.jpg');">
  <!-- Header Content --> 
</header>
```

I have also tried the following way with the same result:

```html
<header style="background-image: url('/images/header.jpg');">
  <!-- Header Content --> 
</header>
```

The structure of the site is like the following:
[image]

My idea is to put the header image for each page into a relative "images" folder.

The issue is: Every subpage loads the header image from the root directory. How would I best go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your HTML document is inside the "articles" folder, the URL for the background image should be `url('images/header.jpg')` – in this case the "images" folder is at the same level as the HTML document, so *no* slash in front of it.